# Protein purification with Cobalt

Tags: transition-metals, chromatography, purification, proteins

> Cobalt exhibits a more specific interaction with histidine tags, resulting in less nonspecific interaction than nickel. For this reason, cobalt is the preferred divalent cation for purifying His-tagged proteins when high purity is a primary concern.

I read this last week, and I'm wondering, why is cobalt like that? What about it causes that?

(Source of quote: https://www.lifetechnologies.com/us/en/home/life-science/protein-biology/protein-biology-learning-center/protein-biology-resource-library/pierce-protein-methods/his-tagged-proteins-production-purification.html)

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a link to or at least a reference to where you read this?  It's a very good question you ask, and I think experts here will want as much background info as possible to construct answers that are helpful for you.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is about immobilized metal affinity chromatography (IMAC), often used to separate a protein expressed in the *E. coli* bacterium from other proteins made by it. The protein of interest is expressed with a histidine-containing affinity tag which binds to immobilized nickel or cobalt at neutral or basic pH. Immobilization is achieved by complexing to NTA (nitrilotriacetic acid) or IDA (iminodiacetic acid). For a discussion of the two ligands, see e.g. [here](https://cube-biotech.com/us/nta-versus-ida-what-s-the-difference).

There are a few proteins from *E. coli* (listed in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304416506000894)) that are known to bind along with the protein of interest. According to a [post written by Damien Soghoian in 2004](http://www.its.caltech.edu/~bjorker/Protocols/nickel_vs_cobalt.pdf), nickel-NTA tends to bind stronger to histidine-tags while cobalt-NTA tends to bind more weakly, but this does not affect specificity (e.g. it would be across the board, not making the separation easier or harder).